# Error accessing Swift dictionary value

Tags: swift

I'm using a provided value to access an array value from a dictionary:

```
print("thisFrom "+thisFrom)
print(values[thisFrom])
let ingredientArr = values[thisFrom] as! [String: Float]
```

But this is the output:

```
thisFrom cup
Optional(["butter": 226.80000000000001, "caster sugar": 225.00730999999999, "granulated sugar": 200.0, "tbsp": 16.0, "ml": 236.58823649999999, "flour": 125.0, "tsp": 48.0, "icing sugar": 125.0])
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I don't understand how it can be returning `nil` , when the `print` lines show the value and resulting array are valid.

I'm using Swift 3.

Comment: deleted mine too ;)

Comment: Does Xcode show you, what type `values` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values[thisFrom]` is not of the type `[String: Float]`. It is `[String: Double]` instead.

Why?

Let's have a look at the value for the key "butter": It is a [floating-point](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID321) number with a precision of more than 6 decimal digits. So it can't be `Float`. That's why the force-cast fails.

Comment: Good explanation about why it's `Double` instead of `Float`.

Comment: Thanks so much @FelixSFD I'm still getting used to typed languages

Answer (score 0):

The unwrap it's referring to is the exclamation point after `as`. What you've written is the same as:

```
let optionalAttemptedCast = values[thisFrom] as? [String: Float]
let ingredientArray = optionalAttemptedCast!
```

Hopefully this makes it clear that what is failing is the cast. That is, `values[thisFrom]` does indeed exist, as you saw from your `print()`, but it is not convertible to type `[String: Float]`.

Answer (score 0):

When I put this code in a playground:

```
let values: [String: Any?] = ["cup": ["butter": 226.80000000000001, "caster sugar": 225.00730999999999, "granulated sugar": 200.0, "tbsp": 16.0, "ml": 236.58823649999999, "flour": 125.0, "tsp": 48.0, "icing sugar": 125.0]]

let thisFrom = "cup"
let ingredientArr = values[thisFrom] as! [String: Float]
```

Xcode gives me the error you're seeing. If I change the line that throws the unwrapping error to

```
let ingredientArr = values[thisFrom] as! [String: Double]
```

It works fine.

Seems like your dictionary is of type `[String: Double]`, not `[String: Float]`.

I would recommend that you change the forced cast to an optional one like this:

```
if let ingredientArr = values[thisFrom] as? [String: Double] {
    // safely casted to [String: Double]
}
```